# Assign the taken image to image view.image

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage

I have image view which is hidden initially. When I click on `TakePhotoButton` and then it takes images and assign it to the image view. then image view is visible.

When I debug my code, I always get my `productImg` is nil, even though `chosenImage` is not nil.

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *productImg;

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
 didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

   UIImage *chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
   self.productImg.hidden=NO;
   self.productImg.image=chosenImage;

   [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];

 }
```

Comment: `productImg` will resolve to the image view when the NIB loads, so it's got nothing to do with this method.  It looks like an error binding the outlet with IB.

Comment: is productImg a IBOutlet or where do you allocate the imageView

Comment: YEs ProductImage is an ImageView IBoutlet

Comment: Nothing related to the issue, just FYI, make IBOutlets weak, don't declare it as strong.

Comment: As your IBOutlet is written as (strong,) I assume you wrote that, as opposed to ctrl drag from IB. In that case, I have to assume your IBOutlet isn't connected to the UIImageView on your ViewController view? This would mean the object is always showing nil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    __block MyViewController *aBlockSelf = self; // Replace MyViewController with your View Controller

    UIImage *chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];

    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
        aBlockSelf.productImg.hidden = NO;
        aBlockSelf.productImg.image = chosenImage;
    }];
}
```

Comment: It is still same problem.

Comment: Can you please double check if your `productImg` is correctly added to the view. May be try by initially un-hiding it once and set any random image on it.

Answer (score 0):

you use following code It may be helpful to you.

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
 didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
{
       UIImage *chosenImage = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
       self.productImg.hidden=NO;
       self.productImg.image=chosenImage;

       [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

Comment: What is the difference between my solution provided.?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have to hide it initially.Since the image will be null it will not be seen any how.

```
   - (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    UIImage *chosenImage;

            chosenImage= info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
            [self.productImg setImage:chosenImage];
            [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];

}
```